# BeginInvoke callback function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have a c# .NET winforms app making this async call:

```
simpleDelegate.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

My function is being called by the delegate and that all works great. The problem is, after the function finishes on the worker thread, I need the main thread to update some controls on my winform. If the worker thread tries to update these controls, .NET freaks out. But I need the main thread to remain responsive to user actions, and then call my function UpdateFormAfterServerCall() ONLY AFTER the worker thread finishes calling the async function.

I would greatly appreciate if you can give me a concise code sample, rather than abstractly explain how to do this. I've read a hundred explanations already, and am just having trouble wiring it together correctly.

Note: Before the BeginInvoke I have:

```
simpleDelegate = new MethodInvoker(CallServer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From different thread if you want to update GUI which is owned by another thread use `MethodInvoker`

```
if(control.InvokeRequired)
control.Invoke( (MethodInvoker) ( ()=> updating_function() ) );
else
updating_function();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Control` class (`Form` is a `Control` as well) has an [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, you can call this from any thread to execute code on the GUI thread.

In addition, `Control` has a convenient `InvokeRequired` property that informs you whether you are on the GUI thread already. You could for instance create the following method in your form:

```
public class MyForm
{
    // ...
    public void UpdateMe()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(UpdateMe));
            return;
        }

       // Code to update the control, guaranteed to be on the GUI thread
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...but I am confused. You are calling UpdateMe from inside UpdateMe. Won't that make an infinite loop? What should call UpdateMe, and how can I trigger that to be called once my function running in the worker thread finishes?

Comment: `InvokeRequired` is only true if executed on another thread than the UI thread, and the `Invoke` there executes `UpdateMe` on the UI thread. Basically it says "if (notOnUiThread) { executeMeOnUIThread(); return; }". This way you can call `UpdateMe` from your worker thread without having to worry about being on the UI thread or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

string result = null;

bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
    // Executes on background thread.
    // UI remains responsive to user activity during this time.
    result = CallServer();
};

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    // Executes on UI thread upon completion.
    resultTextBox.Text = result;
};

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: I tried your code and I still get the same error about controls not being updateable from the worker thread. Where is your code supposed to live? In which function? Does it execute in the worker thread or the main thread?

Comment: The above code should be run from the UI thread, typically within some event handler. The `BackgroundWorker` will first execute the `DoWork` delegate on a worker thread, allowing the UI to remain responsive; upon completion, it will execute `RunWorkerCompleted` on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample [what you want exactly] - 
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

& you can read about all flavours of async here -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.100).aspx